# Python / Selenium - Selenium webdriver search different results than manual search

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I am using a script to track packages on a website. If I run the script I made, sometimes a package shows up as "Unfortunately, the number you entered is not in our tracking system.", but if I type it in and search for it manually then it shows up as "Delivered". An example of this is tracking number RN231029883CA.

I am unsure if this may be caused by some type of spam filter on the website. I see something called spamValidate() in the sites source code but don't know how to check if this is the cause or not.

HTML Code:

```
</div><form id="tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch" name="tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch" method="post" action="/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber?execution=e1s1" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" onsubmit="return spamValidate();"><textarea name="tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch:trackNumbers" id="tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch:trackNumbers" tabindex="0">RN231029883CA,RN231029884CA,</textarea>
                            <!--p class="under-input-txt">Enter up to 24 numbers, separated by commas</p-->
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="large-12 medium-12 small-12 columns"><input id="tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch:submit_button" name="tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch:submit_button" type="submit" value="Track" onclick="if(typeof window.clearFormHiddenParams_tapByTrackSearch_trackSearch=='function'){clearFormHiddenParams_tapByTrackSearch_trackSearch('tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch');}if(typeof window.getScrolling!='undefined'){oamSetHiddenInput('tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch','autoScroll',getScrolling());}" class="button margintop20 marginright" /><input type="hidden" name="autoScroll" />
                                    <a href="#" id="showrecentlytrackeditemsnum" onClick="showRecentlyTrackedItems('byTrack', 'tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch:trackNumbers')" class="button light">Recent items</a>

                                </div>
                            </div><input type="hidden" name="tapByTrackSearch:trackSearch_SUBMIT" value="1" /><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" value="v1Dxx9hSieZwMVPzZZHAPSkIfrSZM1jbO4mNTTN2U0GpxoAFjzFhwEssO/Z0p/uzYyUiHf4E5tIMuqNSqP+dRYKpGsqhkV+2Tm+y5O2kdGHE2HH2c1AYdcgvvjRyYzcsTLGN8xKfqu9JfGmss6QW+w==" /></form>
                    </div>
```

I have run the script a few times and it just seems inconsistent as to when this happens and when it does not. So maybe I need another EC wait somewhere? **(EDIT: I doubt it is an EC wait issue as it happens when I use debug and go line by line)** This is basically my last hurdle that I need to overcome on this project. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

My entire code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException

from openpyxl import Workbook
import bs4 as bs
import math


book = Workbook()
sheet = book.active

i=0
PasteRowNum=1
DeleteTrackingNumbers=0

#Change this value to your starting tracking number
StartingTrackingNumber=231029883

#Change this value to increase or decrease the number of tracking numbers you   want to search overal
TrackingNumberCount = 2

#Number of Tacking Numbers Searched at One Time
QtySearch = 2


for i in range(0,TrackingNumberCount):
    g=i+StartingTrackingNumber
    sheet.cell(row=i+1,column=1).value = 'RN' + str(g) + 'CA,'


TrackingNumbers = []
for col in sheet['A']:
     TrackingNumbers.append(col.value)

MaxRow = sheet.max_row
MaxIterations = math.ceil(MaxRow / QtySearch)


RowCount = 0
LastTrackingThisPass = 0 #QtySearch

#Safari Search Loops
driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver.set_page_load_timeout(10)

for RowCount in range (0,MaxIterations):
    FirstTrackingThisPass = (RowCount)*QtySearch
    LastTrackingThisPass = FirstTrackingThisPass + QtySearch
    print(FirstTrackingThisPass)
    print(LastTrackingThisPass)
    x = TrackingNumbers[FirstTrackingThisPass:LastTrackingThisPass]
    print(x)
    CalcLoops = len(x)
    print(CalcLoops)
    driver.get("https://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber?execution=e1s1")
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]')))

if DeleteTrackingNumbers == 1:

    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]').clear() #send_keys((Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "55")
    print("I tried")

driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]').send_keys(x)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "submit_button")]').send_keys(chr(13))
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mobile_txt_holder, .notfoundcopy")))
SourceCodeTest = driver.page_source
DeleteTrackingNumbers=1

Soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(SourceCodeTest, "lxml") #""html.parser")



objects = []
for each in Soup.find_all("fieldset"):
    each = each.get_text().split("\n") #split the ugly string up
    each = [each[1][-13:], each[5]] #grab the parts you want, rmv extra words
    objects.extend(each)

#If the sheet comes back with "You entered a valid number..." then perform loop one at a time
VaildSearchCheck = "You entered a valid number, but we are not able to show the tracking information for one of the following reasons: "
if VaildSearchCheck == objects[1]:

    objects=[]
    ThisNumber=FirstTrackingThisPass

        for RowCount2 in range(0, CalcLoops): #QtySearch):

            TN = TrackingNumbers[ThisNumber]
            TNum = [TN[0:]]
            #LastTrackingThisPass += QtySearch
            print(TNum)
            driver.get("https://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber?execution=e1s1")
            print(1)
            driver.get_screenshot_as_file("Canada Post A1.png")

            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]')))
            try:
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]').clear()  # send_keys((Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "55")
                print("aaa")
            except NoSuchElementException:
                driver.implicitly_wait(1)
                print("bbb")
                driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]').clear()  # send_keys((Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "55")
            print(2)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]').send_keys(x)
            print(3)
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "submit_button")]').send_keys(chr(13))
            print(4)
            ThisNumber += 1

            WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mobile_txt_holder, .notfoundcopy")))
            SourceCodeTest = driver.page_source
            print(5)
            Soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(SourceCodeTest, "lxml")  # ""html.parser")
            #print(Soup.prettify())

            try:
                #Find the Date:
                Date=driver.find_element_by_class_name("mobile_txt_holder").text
                Date=[Date[1:]]
                print(Date)
                print(1212)

            except NoSuchElementException:
                Date="x"
                print(7777)

            objects.extend(TNum)
            objects.extend(Date)

        print("Yellow")

###Can prob add an else statement to the above if statment to only perform if check worked....
    objectsnum=0
    Stop=int(len(objects)/2)

    #print to excel loop
    for r in range(0,Stop):

        sheet.cell(row=r+PasteRowNum,column=1).value = objects[objectsnum]
        sheet.cell(row=r+PasteRowNum,column=2).value = objects[objectsnum+1]
        objectsnum+=2

    #Excel File Name
    book.save('First Run Test.xlsx')

    #Keep Track of Row Number
    PasteRowNum += QtySearch+1

    print("Loop")
print("Success")
```

part of the code I believe to be the issue:
or RowCount2 in range(0, CalcLoops): #QtySearch):

```
        TN = TrackingNumbers[ThisNumber]
        TNum = [TN[0:]]
        #LastTrackingThisPass += QtySearch
        print(TNum)
        driver.get("https://www.canadapost.ca/cpotools/apps/track/personal/findByTrackNumber?execution=e1s1")
        print(1)
        driver.get_screenshot_as_file("Canada Post A1.png")

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]')))
        try:
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]').clear()  # send_keys((Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "55")
            print("aaa")
        except NoSuchElementException:
            driver.implicitly_wait(1)
            print("bbb")
            driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]').clear()  # send_keys((Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "55")
        print(2)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]').send_keys(x)
        print(3)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[contains(@id, "submit_button")]').send_keys(chr(13))
        print(4)
        ThisNumber += 1

        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".mobile_txt_holder, .notfoundcopy")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an error in my code as I was sending the keys(x) instead of keys(TN), as I couldn't even get it to work intermittently after I started to clean up my code.

I did get it to work every time now by adding a click() before I send keys()

code:

```
trackNumbers = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[contains(@id, "trackNumbers")]')))
    try:
        trackNumbers.click()
        trackNumbers.clear()
```

Comment: I simplified your code some. The `WebDriverWait` returns the element waited for. So, you can assign that to a variable and then do your click and clear using it. The way you had it, it actually scraped the page 3 times where now it only does it once.

Comment: BTW, don't forget to come back and accept this as the answer when you can.

Comment: @JeffC Thanks for the help! I will accept in 2 days when I can :)